# Check if value follow a criteria for subsequent timeseries values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
ID      DATE          PROFIT
2342  2017-03-01       457
2342  2017-06-01       658
2342  2017-09-01       3456
2342  2017-12-01       345
2342  2018-03-01       235
2342  2018-06-01       23
808   2017-03-01       9346
808   2017-06-01       54
808   2017-09-01       314
808   2017-12-01       57
....
....
```

For each ID:

Lets say I want to find out if the Profit has stayed between 200 and 1000.

I want to do it in such a way that the counter( a new column) indicates how many quarters (latest and previous) in succession have satisfied this condition.
If for some reason, one of the intermediate quarters does not match the condition, the counter should reset.

I am thinking of using the **shift** functionality to access/condition on the previous rows, however if there is a better way to check if condition in datetime values, it will be good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Solution if all datetimes are consecutive:

Use [`GroupBy.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html) with `5` for last and previous 4 quarters, compare by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html), add missing values with [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and if encessary cast to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
df['flag'] = (df.groupby('ID')['PROFIT']
                .tail(5)
                .lt(1000)
                .reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)
                .astype(int))
print (df)
     ID        DATE  PROFIT  flag
0  2342  2017-03-01     457     0 #<-6.th value no match
1  2342  2017-06-01     658     1
2  2342  2017-09-01    3456     0
3  2342  2017-12-01     345     1
4  2342  2018-03-01     235     1
5  2342  2018-06-01      23     1
6   808  2017-03-01    9346     0
7   808  2017-06-01      54     1
8   808  2017-09-01     314     1
9   808  2017-12-01      57     1
```

EDIT: for counter column by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) function is possible create consecutive groups by compare by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) (!=) with [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and last use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with multiple by [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) for set to `0` groups with consecutive `0`:

```
df['flag'] = df['PROFIT'].between(200, 1000).astype(int)

df1 = df[['ID','flag']].ne(df[['ID','flag']].shift()).cumsum()

g = df.groupby([df1['ID'], df1['flag']])
df['counter1'] = g.cumcount().add(1).mul(df['flag'])
df['counter2'] = g.cumcount(ascending=False).add(1).mul(df['flag'])
print (df)
     ID        DATE  PROFIT  flag  counter1  counter2
0  2342  2017-03-01     457     1         1         2
1  2342  2017-06-01     658     1         2         1
2  2342  2017-09-01    3456     0         0         0
3  2342  2017-12-01     345     1         1         3
4  2342  2018-03-01     235     1         2         2
5  2342  2018-06-01     230     1         3         1
6   808  2017-03-01     934     1         1         2
7   808  2017-06-01     540     1         2         1
8   808  2017-09-01      34     0         0         0
9   808  2017-12-01      57     0         0         0
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, however I was thinking if there is something more readily available for dealing with datetime values.
Also if I were to sum the continious 1s, and have the summation for each ID, then can i just use the sum function ?

Comment: @asimo - `sum the continious 1s` - Can you explain more? What should be expected output from data?

Comment: the flag should be a cumulative sum if for preceeding 1s, however if there is a 0 in between, it should reset and start again

Comment: So for the 1st ID "2342", the flag at 2018-06-01 should be 3
For the "808"ID, th flag should be 3